# What is the "phone index" in the hidden menu for "phone info"?

Tags: settings, menu

Device: OnePlus 7 Pro (GM1917), Oxygen OS 10.3.8.GM21AA, stock ROM

When I enter the hidden menu `*#*#4636#*#*` and select "Phone info", the first line under "Phone info" says "Select phone index" with a drop-down menu:

- Phone 0
- Phone 1

All of the info listed after "Select phone index" is the exact same no matter which index I choose: Phone 0 or Phone 1.

What is a phone index? Why are they identical?

Comment: Modern Android phones have two system partitions (a/b), one active and the other for installing updates in background. Unless an update had just been installed both partitions are identical. May be this is the info you see.

Comment: Oh. Ok. Thanks. I haven't had a phone that gave me that option before. Not very intuitive menu. Obviously not for me. Wait a minute. All of the info listed below was imei, imsi, freq, dwnld rate,... That shouldn't change unless my SIM changes, right.

Comment: Well it is a hidden menu, may be it is has been designed for people who know what they are looking for not for end-users.

Comment: Ouch! Bazzinga!!!

Comment: Comparing to my Pixel 3a which also has A/B partitions but only 1 phone index (Phone 0), I think this is more related to the dual SIM // cc: @Robert

Comment: Thanks Andrew. That makes sense. I only have one SIM card installed at the moment. Each SIM slot has its own IMEI. If the "Phone Index" is the two slots, the IMEI should be different. As well as not connected. I would think.

Comment: I contacted OnePlus support. They suggested I swap the SIM into the other SIM slot. When I did that, for a very short amount of time; "Phone 0" and "Phone 1" were each listed with their respective IMEI #s. But within seconds, one of them(assumably the empty slot) will duplicate. I still haven't gotten an explanation for this from OnePlus. Any thoughts?